# Bootstrap submenu is not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Submenu is not working properly in below code. Can you please provide the solution?

Here is code,
http://jsfiddle.net/4UVt3/1/

Same fiddle copy-pasted here,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
        <ui class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 2 </a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 3 </a></li>
        </ui>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the submenu dropdown-menu.  Its specified as "ui" not "ul".

Change your submenu dropdown-menu to

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 2 </a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewporta" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 2 </a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You were using ui instead of ul, code above is the working version, below is the change.

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 2 </a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Submenu 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
```